# Shell script using loop, while, grep and awk to find list of terms and corresponding values

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I am searching/ trying to match a list of terms (Ensemble Gene IDs) from my source file with those in the target rnaseq.gtf file. I want to print out the matched/ grep'd ENSEMBLE gene IDs with their corresponding RPKM1 and RPKM2 values to a separate output file.

The source_geneid.csv file looks like:

```
GO Genes ENSEMBLE Gene ID
AATF    ENSG00000108270
ADNP    ENSG00000101126
```

The target_rnaseq.gtf file:

```
chr17   gencodeV7   gene    35306175    35414170    0.669763    +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000108270.5"; transcript_ids "ENST00000225402.4,"; RPKM1 "7.81399"; RPKM2 "8.149"; iIDR "0.000";
chr20   gencodeV7   gene    49505585    49547750    0.862675    -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000101126.8"; transcript_ids "ENST00000371602.2,ENST00000349014.3,ENST00000396029.3,ENST00000396032.1,ENST00000534467.1,"; RPKM1 "12.0082"; RPKM2 "8.55263"; iIDR "0.000";
```

The output file to contain the matched/ grep'd gene_id and it's corresponding RPKM1 and RPMK2 values:

```
ENSG00000108270.5 RPKM1 "7.81399"  RPKM2 "8.149"
ENSG00000101126.8 RPKM1 "12.0082" RPKM2 "8.55263"
```

I've done it on command line:

```
grep -w "ENSG*" target_rnaseq.gtf| awk '{print $10,$13,$14,$15,$16}' >> output.txt
```

I've also tried (thanks fedorqui)

```
while read line
do
  var=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
while read line
do
  var=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
  grep -w "$var" target_rnaseq.gtf | awk '{print $10,$13,$14,$15,$16}' >> output.txt
done < source_geneid.csv
```

but it prints out all the gene id's from the target file.

Comment: This value `RPKM2 "8.149"` is missing from the data?

Comment: Sorry, cutting and pasting mistake. The target file contains RPKM1 and RPKM2 values for all ENSEMBLE gene ids (ENS*). Hope this helps.

Comment: No it doesn't help, what will help if you edit the question to contain the correct file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `target_rnaseq.gtf` seems to be well formed so you can easily process it to make to job easier, for instance getting the values you are interested in is as simple as:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{gsub(/ ?"/,"",$1);print $1,$3,$4}' FS=';' RS='gene_id' rnaseq
ENSG00000108270.5  RPKM1 "7.81399"  RPKM2 "8.149"
ENSG00000101126.8  RPKM1 "12.0082"  RPKM2 "8.55263"
```

Parsing `source_geneid.csv` is trivial:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print $2}' geneid 
ENSG00000108270
ENSG00000101126
```

Putting it all together:

```
$ grep -f <(awk 'NR>1{print $2}' geneid) <(awk 'NR>1{gsub(/ ?"/,"",$1);print $1,$3,$4}' FS=';' RS='gene_id' rnaseq)
ENSG00000108270.5  RPKM1 "7.81399"  RPKM2 "8.149"
ENSG00000101126.8  RPKM1 "12.0082"  RPKM2 "8.55263"
```